# Flask http 404 issue

Tags: python, flask

I ran this code in flask:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And it says this

```
C:\shruti_python> python.exe .\hello.py
* Restarting with stat   
 * Debugger is active!   
 * Debugger PIN: 298-971-142
```

* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

But when I try to access the http url, it give HTTP 404 error.
the ip turns to this http://16.169.147.62/ and gives 
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the proxy for 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: still the same. i added this ip to the do not use proxy server for ip addresses list. still not getting.

Comment: Well something is interfering, I don’t think this is a problem with the code you’ve shown.

Comment: You're not exposing the server to an external address and that redirect has dropped the port number, so you're being redirected, but your python code isn't doing that

Comment: thank you. yes that was the issue. the port number i was using in proxy address and the defaul one in script. Now it works fine.